# Execute batch & .exe files with Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to execute batch & .exe files with a Python Code ?

Because i try to write a programm what should execute a batch and later a .exe file at different paths.

Comment: No effort was put into researching this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the library subprocess
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html